# WinForms dynamic matrix new form with button

Tags: c#, winforms

So I managed to create a dynamic array of text boxes in a new form with a button beneath, but the button is overlapping some of the text boxes as seen in the screenshot:

http://prntscr.com/l7ln4q
[image]

I'd like to add a margin and padding to the array so the button is underneath the array
This is the code that generates the array:

```
    int LinhaText = frmDim.linhas;
    int ColunText = frmDim.colunas;

    const int TEXTBOX_WIDTH = 30;
    const int TEXTBOX_HEIGHT = 30;
    const int SPACING = 0;
    List<List<TextBox>> textboxes = new List<List<TextBox>>();

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < LinhaText; row++)
        {
            List<TextBox> newRow = new List<TextBox>();
            textboxes.Add(newRow);
            for (int col = 0; col < ColunText; col++)
            {

                TextBox newbox = new TextBox();
                newbox.Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH;
                newbox.Height = TEXTBOX_HEIGHT;
                newbox.Top = (row * (TEXTBOX_HEIGHT + SPACING)) + SPACING;
                newbox.Left = (col * (TEXTBOX_WIDTH + SPACING)) + SPACING;
                newRow.Add(newbox);
                this.Controls.Add(newbox);

            }
        }

    }
```

The generation of the array works just fine.

Comment: i would use a grid layout to manage that.

Comment: Im new to programming, what is a grid layout and how do I do it?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/flowlayoutpanel-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Why not add the textboxes to a panel and then add the button. You can even dock the panel and button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you just want a simple solution:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();        // added code    

        for (int row = 0; row < LinhaText; row++)
        {
            List<TextBox> newRow = new List<TextBox>();
            textboxes.Add(newRow);
            for (int col = 0; col < ColunText; col++)
            {

                TextBox newbox = new TextBox();
                newbox.Width = TEXTBOX_WIDTH;
                newbox.Height = TEXTBOX_HEIGHT;
                newbox.Top = (row * (TEXTBOX_HEIGHT + SPACING)) + SPACING;
                newbox.Left = (col * (TEXTBOX_WIDTH + SPACING)) + SPACING;
                newRow.Add(newbox);
                p.Controls.Add(newbox);    // modified code (added textboxes to panel rather than form)

            }
        }

        // added code
        p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(p);
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(p, 0);
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.Text = "hi";
        b1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.Controls.Add(b1);
        this.Controls.SetChildIndex(b1, 1);
    }
```